# MassTransit's PublisherConfirmation option no longer exists

Tags: masstransit

Upgrading to MassTransit 4.x, overtop RabbitMQ.  My application configuration was using `PublisherConfirmation` set to true, to ensure message delivery without the overhead of transactions.  (In least, that was what the docs used to say.)

In MT 4.x., it appears that `PublisherConfirmation` no longer exists.

I haven't found any info (yet) on why this went away, or what replaces it moving forward.  Essentially, I don't want fire-and-forget; if the message doesn't reach the queue I want an exception.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean that when you use `Send` and there is no destination queue, you want an exception?

Comment: I mean that if RabbitMQ is down for some reason, client code should be made aware that publishing the message failed.

Comment: Have you experienced situations when RMQ is down and your service is up? From our experience, RMQ is one of the most reliable pieces of infrastructure.

Comment: Haven't had any problems, but if PublisherConfirmation exists, and transactions are also possible, one assumes that it's because things can go wrong. Otherwise, they wouldn't server any purpose - just publish the message and forget about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To configure `PublisherConfirmation` using MT 4.x or later, that option is now configured on the host, instead of the bus.

https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport/Configuration/IRabbitMqHostConfigurator.cs#L24

Comment: Thanks - appreciate the answer!